# Trigger Enter on dynamic field

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

i want to put trigger enter to button add more on my dynamic field like on the picture below, but it only works on the first input field. how do i put trigger enter on the other field?

```js
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("sn");
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      document.getElementById("add").click();
    }
  });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sn" name="sn[]" placeholder="SN" class="form-control">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40mPX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementById("sn")` function only return first child, That's why your code works on the first input field. You can use `getElementsByClassName('you_class_name')`.

Maybe you can do something like below,

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
            text = target.value;
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
           document.getElementById("add").click();
        }
    }, false);

 </script>
```

Comment: still doesnt work. is there anything i should change on my script too?